# How does the Northern shore of Lake Balaton compare to the Southern shore?

Tags: food-and-drink, weather-and-climate, hungary

We're planning a 5-day holiday to Lake Balaton and I have a few general questions.

Is the northern shore colder in comparison to the southern shore? 
What are the cons/pros of each shore, if we're a quiet, calm and vegetarian couple?

I've heard that the four main tourist towns can be quite loud at night, so that's out of the question. But I haven't heard anything about the weather & temperature of water/air.

Cheap hotels or hostels are fine by us.

EDIT: I mainly like to know whether the air & water is warmer on the southern shore, and if there's anything to eat for a vegetarian?

Comment: What is your question? Comparing what on each shore? If it's temperature what's the link with accommodation? Make it more clear. For example, put your question at the end, so that it's very clear!

Comment: You've asked several questions in one, which makes it difficult to argue, and not in line with the philosophy of the website (see [faq]). I'd suggest splitting them into several questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The southern shore is shallower than the northern shore and the shallow water warms up quicker so the water is warmer there. The shallow water is also great for families with small children, but it's not too great if you want to swim. Sometimes you have to walk too much before the water is deep enough for swimming.